# Uptime of K8s Service over a period of time - Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, service, prometheus, grafana

What is the simplest way to find out the Availability of a K8s service over a period of time, lets say 24h. Should I target a pod or find a way to calculate service reachability

Comment: subsets of pods may be respawned, that does not means service is down.

Comment: @P.... Your correct, how do you suggest to go abou this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to not approach it from a binary (is it up or down) but from a "how long does it take to serve requests" perspective. In other words, phrase your availability in terms of SLOs. You can get a very nice automatically generated SLO-based alter rules from [PromTools](https://promtools.dev/alerts/latency). One concrete example rule from there, showing the PromQL part:

```yaml
1 - (
 sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{job="prometheus",le="0.10000000000000001",code!~"5.."}[30m]))
 /
 sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{job="prometheus"}[30m]))
)
```

Above captures the ratio of how long it took the service to serve non-500 (non-server errors, that is, assumed good responses) in less than 100ms to overall responses over the last 30 min with `http_request_duration_seconds` being the histogram, capturing the distribution of the requests of your service.

Comment: So if I had only 2 requests within 30min with 1 of them below the threshold, the system will consider it had a 50% uptime. Even though theoretically, system could have fulfilled another 100 requests within the SLO. I'm thinking maybe there has to be a watcher service to generate a continuous load to provide an even measurement throughout the month, especially if there are several indicators (not only HTTP requests durations) which I want to combine sequentially (by multiplying respetive uptimes)